# xslt performance issue with large if conditions

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

In my xslt i have code like

```
 <xsl:param name="acceptType"/>
 <xsl:template match="element-1|element-2............|element-n>
   <xsl:if test=".!=''">           
         <xsl:if test="not(contains($acceptType, 'xml'))">
            <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pARRAY"/>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
```

Here i have nearly 1000 elements .Because of this condition checking we are having the performance issue.Is there any alternative way for doing this?.I am thinking to put a global boolean variable and want to check that variable.Is it the right way to increase performance.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How do you know that that construct is responsible for the performance problems? Which XSLT processor exactly do you use? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: I don't have idea on profiling

Comment: Please poste (part of your) XML

Comment: @Shnugo it is very big one.If you have any doubt ask me .

Comment: That's why I wrote **part of**. It's difficult without knowledge of the structure...

Comment: which version of xslt?

Comment: I find it very unlikely that the `match="x|y|z"` is slowing things down. This typically boils down to a kind of lookup table. Instead, I'd guess your `test=". != ''"` is a possible culprit, as it requires getting the _value of_ the entire subtree under the current node. This operation is way more expensive than checking an element name.

Comment: @Abel not that condition.I mean if condition

Comment: I was talking about the if-condition. The match-pattern is unlikely to cause trouble. Unless you have left out the actual part that causes perf issues? The second if-condition will be pre-compiled, it is based on a global param. A trick to test performance is to take an offending if-condition, match-pattern, predicate expression and replace it with something like `position() mod 1000 = 0`. This is typically a very fast expression. You'll get wrong output, of course, but if it is faster, you have found a possible bottleneck.

Comment: Another thing to consider is: are you testing properly? I.e., are you precompiling the XSLT and then running it several times against several input? If you parse/compile it on each run, it will have a sign. overhead due to recompilation.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely measure rather than guess regarding performance.

But here are some alternative ideas in the meantime to eliminate the 1000 elements in your single match template:

1. Change to `match="*"` and then add separate `match="element-i"` templates for
   each of the other `i`..`N` elements not in the original 1000.  This should
   help if `N` is much less than 1000, or see #2:
2. Change to `match="*[` *some condition* `]`, where `some condition`
   covers each of your `element-1`, `element-2`, ...

   - `string(number(substring-after(local-name(), '-')) = 'Nan'` would
     test if the matching element name ended with a `-` *number*.
   - `child` would test for a common child element.
   - `@attr > 0` would test for positive `@attr` values
   - etc.

Whether any of these are faster or not, again, should be determined empirically for your particular XSLT processor.  However, if applicable, these alternatives could have a code maintenance, if not performance, advantage at least.

---

**Update**:  [Abel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412125/xslt-performance-issue-with-large-if-conditions/33413566#comment54628441_33412125) doubting that `match="x|y|z"` would be sinking performance makes sense.  Try replacing what concerns him more, the `test=". != ''"` test, with `test="node()"` instead:

```
 <xsl:param name="acceptType"/>
 <xsl:template match="element-1|element-2............|element-n>
   <xsl:if test="node()">           
       <xsl:if test="not(contains($acceptType, 'xml'))">
          <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
             <xsl:value-of select="$pARRAY"/>
          </xsl:element>
       </xsl:if>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

This condition will be true for non-empty matching elements but will avoid asking for the string value of the current node (which you don't really need anyway) to be calculated.

Comment: Actually those elements are not similar.The elements are like v1:orderLineAttachment|v1:productOfferingRelationship|v1:verificationQuestion|v1:lineOfBusiness.......................I have other elements are also more.

Comment: Actually i am talking about the if condition

Comment: So did `<xsl:if test="node()">` help?

Answer (score 1):

In xslt 2.0 I'd do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="element" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:variable name="acceptedElements">
        <element name="a1"/>
        <element name="a3"/>
        <element name="a5"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="key('element-by-name', local-name(), $acceptedElements)">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```